# How can I add below customized columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, metrics, summary

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a Dictionary of series
d = {'Name':pd.Series(['Tom','James','Ricky','','Steve','Tom','Jack',
   'Lee','David','','Betina','Andres']),
   'Age':pd.Series([25,,25,23,30,29,23,'NULL',40,30,51,46]),
   'Rating':pd.Series([4.23,3.24,3.98,2.56,3.20,4.6,3.8,3.78,2.98,4.80,4.10,3.65])
}

#Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

summary = df.describe(include='all').T
print(summary)
```

How can I create two columns to get total_duplicate_value_count and total_null_value_count. And then add it to existing **summary** data frame ?

```
Expected Output :
column_name     total_null_value_count  total_duplicate_value_count    count  ...
Name            2                       1                              12     ...
Age             2                       3                              12     ...
Rating          0                       0                              12     ...
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Updated the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

First append null value count `isna().sum()` as new row, transpose, then append new colum with difference between `count` and `unique` as duplicate count:

```
df.describe(include='all').append(df.isna().sum().rename('total_null_value_count')).T.assign(total_duplicate_count = df.describe(include='all').loc['count'] - df.describe(include='all').loc['unique'])
```